# REST::Client vs LWP::UserAgent Perl class to access Google API?

Tags: perl, rest

For Google API, should we use [`REST::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client)
 or its base class [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent)?

I see no particular reason to use `REST::Client`, but this class was created with some purpose. What is that purpose?

Comment: This isn't an answer, because I'm unfamiliar with `REST::Client`, but looking at the source, it's not a subclass of `LWP::UserAgent` at all, but a thing that provides its own methods through both `LWP::UserAgent` and [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI). Somewhat like [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize), it provides a higher-level functional layer but allows access to the underlying `LWP::UserAgent` object through the `getUseragent` method. I think you must experiment with it before you know whether it suits you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST::Client is mostly a wrapper around LWP::UserAgent. It adds some methods for easier access to functionality needed for REST (i.e. DELETE, PUT, PATCH.. etc methods, XML parsing). If you don't need any of these you could simply use LWP::UserAgent directly.

Comment: `DELETE`, `PUT`, and `PATCH` are standard HTTP methods, and not specific to REST services. (I refuse to talk about *RESTful*.) I don't see where `REST::Client` supports XML parsing?

Comment: @Borodin: "responseXpath () - A convienience wrapper that returns a XML::LibXML xpath context for the body content. Assumes the content is XML.". And yes,  methods like DELETE, PUT... are standard HTTP but not specifically exposed in LWP. REST::Client is just a small wrapper around LWP::UserAgent which might make the code more easy to understand for developers familiar with REST.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately CPAN is rather polluted with modules claiming to support Google API Services. I've often found it frustrating that I've had to use different modules for each service and typically try out a few before finding each of these. Once you become familiar with the OAUTH2 dance and managing your tokens you can use a range of modules to perform lower level queries to directly access the API Endpoints. It is worth searching around for Swagger/OpenAPI resources as I expect that this is what the Ninjas probably use as you can probably dynamically configure a client based on the Swagger/OpenAPI yaml or json config using something like [OpenAPI::Client](https://metacpan.org/pod/OpenAPI::Client). 
But beyond a simple OAUTH2 client to gain access to the endpoints ( there are many examples if you search for 'perl'+'Google api'+'OAUTH2'+'Client'+'example' ) often the services are sophisticated enough to require some decent functionality to manipulate the payloads. 
At the time of writing I'm actually in the process of trying to clean up a rather poorly implemented rough code base that you can install by doing

```
see https://pscott-au.github.io/WebService-Google-Client/
```

This isn't aligned with the CPAN version. One handy tool included to help get started is a little command line utility `goauth` that runs a mini weberver to help you generate tokens etc. In the examples folder you can see how you can use this to send an email through the Gmail API service which was my initial motivation.

There is a commitment for ongoing development of this ( and potentially move into cpan once I consider it of suitable general use. Likely to be released under a different namespace if I can't align with the WebService-Google-Client author.

If you are interested in specific use cases or just want a hand using the Google API services with Perl then reach out and I'll help if I can.